# Fulfilling maximum customer orders

Tags: algorithm, optimization

> There is an inventory of products like eg. A- 10Units, B- 15units, C- 20Units and so on. We have some customer orders of some products like customer1{A- 10Units, B- 15Units}, customer2{A- 5Units, B- 10Units}, customer3{A- 5Units, B- 5Units}. The task is fulfill maximum customer orders with the limited inventory we have. The result in this case should be filling customer2 and customer3 orders instead of just customer1.[The background for this problem is a realtime online retail scenario, where we have millions of customers and millions of products and we are trying to fulfill the orders as efficiently as possible]

How do I solve this?Is there an algorithm for this kind of problem, something like optimisation?

Edit: The requirement here is fixed. The only aim here is maximizing the number of fulfilled orders regardless of value. But we have millions of users and millions of products.

Comment: I tried to start with a greedy approach. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Efficient, is a moot point when it comes to real world problems like this. Most efficient for the warehouse/s, picking staff, company profitability or customer satisfaction. It appears that you are aiming for customer satisfaction but one has to bear in mind that satisfying a lot of small customers is not necessarily better that keeping the big customers sweet when considering the bottom line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem includes as a special case a knapsack problem. To see why consider only one product A: the storage amount of the product is your bag capacity, the order quantities are the weights and each rock value is 1. Your problem is to maximize the total value you can fit in the bag.

Don't expect an exact solution for your problem in polynomial time...

An approach I'd go for is a random search: make a list of the orders and compute a solution (i.e. complete orders in sequence, skipping the orders you cannot fulfill). Then change the solution by applying a permutation on the orders and see if it's better.

Keep going with search until time runs out or you're happy with the solution.

Comment: @drew: The opposite. If you solve this then you solved the knapsack also. This is a multi-dimensional version of the knapsack problem (each product being a dimension). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by DP.
Firstly sort all your orders with respect to A in increasing order.

Use this DP :

```
DP[n][m][o] = DP[n-a][m-b][o-c] + 1 where n-a>=0 and m-b >=0 o-c>=0
DP[0][0][0] = 1;
```

Do bottom up computation :

```
Set DP[i][j][k] = 0 , for all i =0 to Amax; j= 0 to Bmax; k = 0 to Cmax
For Each n : 0 to Amax
   For Each m : 0 to Bmax
      For Each o : 0 to Cmax
         if(n>=a && m>=b && o>= c)
         DP[n][m][o] = DP[n-a][m-b][o-c] + 1;
```

You will then have to find the max value of DP[i][j][k] for all values of i,j,k possible. This is your answer. - O(n^3)

Comment: It was asked to me in a real time retail scenario. I mean we have millions of products and millions of customers.

Comment: Then you should go greedy, Sort wrt to A and compute your answer by picking top orders which you can satisfy. Do this for B and C again. The max from these three approaches should be reported as a good selection.

Answer (score 0):

Reams have been written about order fulfillment and yet no one has come up with a standard answer. The reason being that companies have different approaches and different requirements.
There are so many variables that a one size solution that fits all is not possible.
You would have to sit down and ask hundreds of questions before you could even start to come up with an approach tailored to your customers needs.
Indeed those needs might also vary, based on the time of year, the day of the week, what promotions are currently being run, whether customers are ranked, numbers of picking and packing staff/machinery currently employed, nature, size, weight of products, where products are in the warehouse, whether certain products are in fast/automated picking lines, standard picking faces or in bulk. The list can appear endless.
Then consider whether all orders are to be filled or are you allowed to partially fill an order and back-order out of stock products.
Does the entire order have to fit in a single box or are multiple box orders permitted.
Are you dealing with multiple warehouses and if so can partial orders be sent from each or do they have to be transferred for consolidation.
Should precedence be given to local or overseas orders.
The amount of information that you need at your finger tips before you can even start to plan a methodology to fit your customers specific requirements can be enormous and sadly, you are not going to get a definitive answer. It does not exist.
Whilst I realise that this is not a) an answer or b) necessarily a welcome post, the hard truth is that you will require your customer to provide you with immense detail as to what it is that they wish to achieve, how and when.

You job, initially, is the play devils advocate, in attempting to nail them down.
P.S. Welcome to S.O.